# Disabling the Android hide keyboard soft button

Tags: android

On a device with a virtual set of hard buttons, is there any way to show the virtual back button instead of showing the virtual close keyboard button when user is interacting with an EditText widget? For example, on the Nexus 7 Android 4.1:

[image: Screen shot of nexus 7 soft buttons with close keyboard | home | apps]

For this dialog, when editing text, I'd rather see:

[image: Screen shot of nexus 7 soft buttons with back | home | apps]

I'd like a dialog I bring up to only allow the keyboard action button -- search in my case -- or the back button to be pressed. It doesn't make sense to hide the keyboard.

Edit: as pointed out below, physical back button does same as virtual hide keyboard button when keyboard is open: it closes the keyboard.

Comment: Except... that's what people are expecting it to do. I don't believe there is a way to override it.

Comment: Closing the keyboard is what the back button *does* when the keyboard is open.  Android 4.0 doesn't even show that special symbol; it continues to show the Back symbol even when the keyboard is open.  And remember that there are lots of devices with physical Back buttons that the software can't hide or show.

Comment: Good point about physical back button Wyzard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to root the phone and install a custom rom to do that. But even if there was another way, I'd recommend against it since the back button will still work and will hide the keyboard as you wish and also because nexus users expect that button to work in the default way and if a certain app overrides that behavior, it'll lead to an inconsistent user experience which is never good.

Comment: Anup, that is what I was going to experiment with next: close dialog when keyboard is dismissed. Because this would be the functionality, I was hoping there was a way to change the icon shown per my question. I may ask separate question whether doing what I propose -- programatically dismiss dialog when keyboard is closed by user -- is OK Android UI guideline-wise.

Comment: Anup, sorry if deleting my comment was confusing. I felt it better to ask in separate question. Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_LEFT) {
     // make the action you wan't for the back key here
     return false;
}
```